# MySQL select rows with timestamp closest to but not exceeding the given timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks something as below

```
state_history
+---------------------+-----------+----------------+      +
| state_added_time    | entity_id | state_id       | .... |
+---------------------+-----------+----------------+      |
| 2015-05-15 13:24:22 |         1 |              1 |      |
| 2015-05-15 13:29:44 |         3 |              2 |      |
| 2015-05-15 13:34:26 |         2 |              2 |      |
| 2015-05-15 14:24:28 |         1 |              3 |      |
| 2015-05-15 14:24:30 |         2 |              3 |      |
| 2015-05-15 14:26:32 |         3 |              5 |      |
| 2015-05-15 14:26:34 |         3 |              3 |      |
.......
```

My intention is to know the states of all entities at any given time. For example, if the timestamp received from the application is `2015-05-15 14:25:00` then the expected output should be:

```
state_history
+---------------------+-----------+----------------+      +
| state_added_time    | entity_id | state_id       | .... |
+---------------------+-----------+----------------+      |
| 2015-05-15 14:24:28 |         1 |              3 |      |
| 2015-05-15 14:24:30 |         2 |              3 |      |
| 2015-05-15 13:29:44 |         3 |              2 |      |
.......
```

That is, to know the last state change which took place for each entity before or at the given time. The interval between state change is not fixed. Thus I cannot have 2 time boundaries and find rows between them.

I have tried using `TIMEDIFF` but failed to get the desired output. Could anyone please guide me on the path I should take?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. I tried the answers and noticed that the queries take quite a lot of time to fetch the rows when executed on the actual database. Probably because the fields `entity_id` and `state_id` are foreign keys to two other tables.
Now that this is known is there any way to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: Just to clarify, you will have one row for each entity_id right? The one that is greatest, but less than the timestamp given?

Comment: @McAdam331. That is correct.

Comment: In my answer, if an entity_id does not have a row less than the given timestamp, it will not be returned. Is that okay? Also, you said closest to but not exceeding, what if the time column is the same? In other words, can the time be less than or equal to the parameter, or strictly less than?

Comment: @McAdam331: That's ok. Thanks for the quick answer. :) I am trying out all suggestions and will choose the one best suitable for me.

Comment: Of course, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it using variables:

```
SELECT entity_id, state_added_time, state_id
FROM (
  SELECT state_added_time, state_id,
          @row_number:= CASE WHEN @entity = entity_id THEN @row_number+1
                             ELSE 1
                        END AS row_number,
          @entity:=entity_id AS entity_id   
  FROM state_history
  WHERE state_added_time <= '2015-05-15 14:25:00'
ORDER BY entity_id, state_added_time DESC ) t
WHERE t.row_number = 1
```

`@row_number` is being reset each time a new `entity_id` is encountered. Within each `entity_id`, a value of `@row_number = 1` points to the most recent record.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2d8f/2)

Comment: Thanks. This proved to the fastest among all other solutions since this one does not involve any joins. :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT h.*
  FROM 
(
  SELECT entity_id, MAX(state_added_time) state_added_time
    FROM state_history
   WHERE state_added_time <= '2015-05-15 14:25:00'
  GROUP BY entity_id
) q JOIN state_history h
    ON q.entity_id = h.entity_id
   AND q.state_added_time = h.state_added_time
```

Output:

```
|      state_added_time | entity_id | state_id |
|-----------------------|-----------|----------|
| May, 15 2015 13:29:44 |         3 |        2 |
| May, 15 2015 14:24:28 |         1 |        3 |
| May, 15 2015 14:24:30 |         2 |        3 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba01f/4)** demo

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can use some simple aggregation. All you need is the `MAX()` function to get the largest time for each entity_id, on the condition that it is less than a given timestamp.

Once you have that time for each entity_id, you'll need to join it back to the original table in order to get the state_id value as well. It looks like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM state_history s
JOIN(
  SELECT entity_id, MAX(state_added_time) AS maxTime
  FROM state_history
  WHERE state_added_time < '2015-05-15 14:25:00'
  GROUP BY entity_id) tmp ON tmp.entity_id = s.entity_id AND tmp.maxTime = s.state_added_time;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc158/3) example.

Comment: Optionally, you can add an `ORDER BY s.entity_id` clause at the end if it helps. Otherwise, they're ordered arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this in terms of sets.  You need a set of data containing the maximum date which is less than or equal to the date provided grouped by entity.  This set of data can be generated as an inline view. (I called B) Once you have this set, join it back to the base set to join it back to base set to get additional fields.

```
SELECT SH.state_Added_time, SH.Entity_Id, SH.State_Id
FROM state_history SH
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT max(state_added_Time) MT, entity_ID
  FROM state_history
  WHERE state_Added_Time <= '2015-05-15 14:25:00'
  GROUP BY entity_Id) B
 on B.MT=Sh.State_Added_time
and B.Entity_ID=SH.Entity_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM state_history WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(state_added_time) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-15 14:25:00')
```

Comment: This will select all rows that happened before that timestamp, but it does not do any grouping. The OP wants the latest row for each entity_id, as long as that latest row is before the given timestamp. Also, if the column is stored as `timestamp`, there is no need to use a function on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can just do

```
SELECT * From state_history where state_added_time  <= '2015-05-15 14:25:00' ORDER BY  state_added_time DESC
```

Comment: This will select all rows that happened before that timestamp, but it does not do any grouping. The OP wants the latest row for each entity_id, as long as that latest row is before the given timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*
from (select Max(state_added_time) AS maxts, entity_id 
      FROM   state_history
      WHERE state_added_time <= "2015-05-15 14:25:00" 
      GROUP  BY entity_id
) as m inner join state_history s 
on s.state_added_time = m.maxts
and s.entity_id = m.entity_id
```

sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884ee/12/0